# Bootstrap input field call function on return keypress if field is focused

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an input group in bootstrap which is an icon, a field and a button - for the purposes of user interface experience I would like the return key to call the function attached to the search button but only if that field is in focus.

Is this possible with native bootstrap or will some form of jQuery be needed? I wouldn't want the return keypress to be permanently used to activate this function, only if the user is using this input search field.

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="another-location">Search for another location</label>

  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Location"><span class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw"></span></div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control gllpSearchField" id="another-location" placeholder="A location" name="another-location" />

    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
    </span>                             
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are these inside an actual `form`? If so, why not make the button an `input` of `type="submit"`? Then return will fire the form submit. Any search functionality would then attach to the form's `submit` event instead. Can you show the rest of the HTML too? Q: Where is "the function attached to the search button"

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. This is in a form but there is an overall submit button this is just one part of the form and if the user interacts with this field it performs a google map search so an overall submit button is at the bottom of the page to update all details. Regarding the function, I had an ID on the button class which is fired via  a jquery onclick event. Its a lot of code but basically involves looking up an address in googlemaps and showing a pin. All I was concerned with is how if a field is focused in bootstrap, a return press could call a function. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you need Jquery :

```
$('#another-location').keypress(function(event){
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if(keycode == '13'){
           alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox, here submit your form'); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Raymond thanks for your reply and confirming what I thought - I was unsure if there was a neater method for bootstrap to automatically know that the field and the button in the group where linked so enter key would auto bind with that. Thanks for that code example I will have a play with that now.

Comment: Use `$(this).parent().find('button').click();` to press the button.

Comment: Thanks for that extra tip on the button click Cobote